# how to backup oracle databasae when operating system is down

Tags: database, oracle, backup

i am researching on how to backup oracle database when my operating system is down
if you give me some useful comments or introduce me some useful sources and books or maybe video tutorial
i'll be so thankful

Comment: Why would the operating system be down while you're backing up the database?  If we assume that the database was shut down cleanly and that the file system is mounted on some other server where you're doing the backup, I suppose it's possible.  But it's an exceptionally odd thing to want to do in the first place that I'd question what underlying problem you're really trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the database on the downed server shut down cleanly, and you have access to the disk containing all the datafiles, yes you can do this in the same way that we used to clone databases using a copy datafiles and re-create the control file.

Have you got  a backup of the controlfile to trace, e.g.

ALTER DATABASE BACKUP CONTROLFILE TO TRACE;

Then locate the trace file, and amend it (new database SID).

If you don't have a controlfile backup, you might need to build it manually, the key thing being to ensure all the datafiles are included.

THis method also of course relies on the source and target database versions being the same, and the OS having the same endianess.

Comment: hi sir
how can  i be in contact with you ?
if you give me your email i'll be so thankful...